# C++ - Expected primary expression before '(' token AND missing template arguments before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-errors

I define

```
typedef std::map< int, std::set<int> > SparseMap;
```

Then I try to insert a pair in that way:

```
pair<SparseMap::iterator,bool> result;
result = sparseBlue.insert(SparseMap::value_type(row, set(col)) ); //errors
   if(result.second)
         cout << "Inserted" << endl;
```

- *row* and *col* are integer matrix coordinates
- sparseBlue is declared as `SparseMap sparseBlue;`

Why do I get those errors at the line in which I .insert?

Comment: What happens when you use `std::pair<SparseMap::iterator,bool> result;` instead of `pair<SparseMap::iterator,bool> result;`?

Comment: What is `row`? What is `col`? What is `sparseBlue`?

Comment: Erroneous ; on the third line as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver the problem still remains (i'm using `namespace std;`)

Comment: @juanchopanza post updated

Comment: @JonathanPotter updated, thanks

Comment: I don't see how that duplicate can be right (and I didn't vote to close as duplicate)

Comment: You probably want `set<int>`.

Comment: Is the suggestion to use `insert(typename SparseMap::value_type(row, set(col)));` ?

Comment: I think @T.C. has it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve We should not ever have to guess

Comment: @JonathanPotter `typename` resolves the first error! thank you! But the missing template error still remains

Comment: I believe `typename` there just makes the compiler marginally less confused. I don't see any reason you need to keep it in the final solution.

Comment: I was just curious if that was why that particular dupe had been chosen; I would not have expected it to be needed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is that you can insert into the map before you add items:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    std::map<int, set<int>> sparseBlue;

    // insert empty item
    auto iter = sparseBlue.insert(std::make_pair(row, std::set<int>()));

    // did a new item get inserted?
    cout << "The item did " << (iter.second?"":"not") << " get inserted\n";

    // add item to set 
    (*iter.first).  // the map iterator
           second.  // the set
           insert(col); // what we want to do 
}
```

The return value of [std::map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) returns a `std::pair`, denoting the iterator to the inserted item, and `true` or `false` depending on whether a new item was inserted.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/wab2d6)

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustive example! Now it's all clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe @T.C and @Lightness Races in Orbit had the right idea with `std::set<int>` being needed. The only problem is `std::set<T>` doesn't have a constructor that takes a constructor that takes a single item of type T (int in this case).

Assuming you actually need a set as the value in the map, then you'll probably want something like:

```
std::set<int> tmpSet;
tmpSet.insert(col);
result = sparseBlue.insert(std::make_pair(row, tmpSet));
```

Comment: That's it! It works also with `result = sparseBlue.insert(SparseMap::value_type(row, tmpSet));`

Comment: In c++11 set has a constructor that takes an initializer list, so doing it without the separate step is certainly possible.

Comment: oh yeah whoops. haha owned by 41 rep. +1

Comment: @Jonathan Potter:

Forgot my shift when I hit enter :) 

I think the initializer list must be constant at compile time. I'm not sure though, and it wasn't evident from looking at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list. Would love to find this out, actually, since I always assumed the initializer list had to be constant.

Comment: @AndrewHall It works at least in some compilers: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/759a9b42998c40a5

Comment: @Jonathan Potter: You're absolutely right! The more you learn. I'm surprised this didn't work with rh0x's compiler. Thanks for showing me.

Comment: @AndrewHall you answer resolves the problems but I choose PaulMcKenzie's answer as correct because he gives me a very clear example on how to use map with set and this helps me a lot.